# How can I know whether the response I receive from a web server is cached response or not

Tags: caching, performance-testing

I am using a Rest API from where I call the salesforce.com api. I am performing load testing and stress testing etc. So I am bothered about whether my responses are cached or not. I am receiving responses in json format
And the other factor is do I really have to worry about my responses being cached while performing performance testing??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all: will salesforce.com api be called during the test? If so, do you have an agreement with salesforce team (or maybe they provide specific api for load-testing)? If you do not heve such agreement, you should make some stub of salesforce api and use it during the test, because your test may cause problem on salesforce side or (more likely) you'll be banned.

Caching responses of your app/site generally unwanted, cause in load-testing you're generally interested in worst-case scenario. Or, of cached answers you'll get, you may tune you test accordingly.

Most of http servers and proxies understand headers
`Cache-control: no-cache`
`Pragma: no-cache`
The only general way of cheking whether it works is to inspect your backend server logs. Or caching server logs, if anwsers from cache are somehow marked.

Depending on cache solution you use, it's possible to mark cached responses some other way, i.e. in nginx you can add header:

```
X-Cache: $upstream_cache_status
```

See details on http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#.24upstream_cache_status